# Nginx proxy_pass is ignored if static file exists

Tags: proxy, nginx

I'm trying to get nginx to *always* proxy certain requests, even if a static file exists. I have the proxying working fine, except nginx seems to insist on serving a static version of the file even if a proxy directive has been declared.

So in the config below, if a file named "/siteroot/static/members/page.html" existed, it would be (incorrectly) served directly instead of proxying, but if I remove the file, then proxying proceeds as expected. How can I force nginx to always proxy?

I'm running nginx 0.7.67, here's the full config:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  logs/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  .XXX.net .XXXnet.net;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    location ^~ /members {
             access_log logs/members-access.log;
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5010;
    }

    location ^~ /search {
             access_log logs/search-access.log;
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5010;
    }

    location / {
             root /siteroot/static;
    }


    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page    404  %(ROOT)s/web/XXX/public/404.html;
    error_page    500 502 503 504  %(ROOT)s/web/XXX/public/50x.html;
}
```

Comment: Does the request end up in the `members-access.log` or is it redirected to `location /`? Normally a rule like `^~ something` would take precedence over `/`.

Comment: Also, I'm voting for a move to `serverfault` since this doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Comment: @WoLpH: it goes in members-access, no matter how served.

Comment: @WoLpH: No argument with the move -- how is it done, should I just cross-post and then remove it here?

Comment: @Rick Morrison: No need for cross posting, if enough people vote (5 are needed) than it will be moved automatically.

Comment: @Rick Morrison: in that case I'm not sure what the problem is. Are the error logs telling you anything? You can try to add a `proxy_next_upstream off` directive so it will always be forced to use your backend.

Comment: @WolpH: Thanks -- Error logs are empty. Adding the `proxy_next_upstream` directive has no effect.

Comment: @Rick Morrison: I don't think it will help here, but instead of `location ^~ /search` you can also do `location /search`. For the rest, try to enable debug logging (`error_log logfile debug`) and see if that gives anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

After turning on nginx debugging, it turns out that nginx is correctly reverse-proxying to the back-end application. It is the back-end Pylons application that is serving the static file as-is instead of executing a controller. Nginx seems to be functioning properly.